# CAN communication between two STM32's

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, communication, can-bus

I want to establish communication between two devices via CAN protocol: one is STM32L496RET (80 MHz - normal CAN) and the other is STM32G474RET6 (170 MHz - FDCAN). I use the TLT9251VLEXUMA1 transceiver.

1. the STM32L496RET has normal CAN 2.0B
2. the STM32G474RET6 has an FDCAN module, but with CAN 2.0B support.
   From datasheat:
   *"
   The three CAN modules (FDCAN1, FDCAN2 and FDCAN3) are compliant with ISO 11898-1
   (CAN protocol specification version 2.0 part A, B) and CAN FD protocol specification
   version 1.0. "*
   3.TLT9251VLEXUMA1 is fully compliant with ISO 11898-2 (2016) (i.e. CAN 2.0).

I want to communicate only through version 2.0 - it is enough for me.
If I understand everything correctly, it should work on such a configuration.
Of course, I have two 120R resistors in the network.

The problem is because I can't receive any message on STM32L4 device - I've checked network on oscilloscope and looks ok - the data are transmitting.
I can't receive any interrupt with receives data.
I think it can be time bit problem.

for calculating bit timings I use this calculator:
http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/ - for both devices (because I use FDCAN in classic mode so it should be the same). I want to achieve 500kbit/s. Sample-Point at 75%.|

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

My config;

STM32l4 configuration:

```
void CanManager::Init()
        {
            HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
            mCanInstance.Instance = CAN1;
            mCanInstance.Init.Prescaler = 8;
            mCanInstance.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
            mCanInstance.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
            mCanInstance.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_14TQ;
            mCanInstance.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_5TQ;
            mCanInstance.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
            mCanInstance.State = HAL_CAN_STATE_RESET;
            status = HAL_CAN_Init(&mCanInstance);
            if (status != HAL_OK)
            {
                // TODO_LOG
            }

            mCanFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;
            mCanFilter.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0;
            mCanFilter.FilterMaskIdLow = 0;
            mCanFilter.FilterIdHigh = 0;
            mCanFilter.FilterIdLow = 0;
            mCanFilter.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
            mCanFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
            mCanFilter.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
            mCanFilter.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
            mCanFilter.FilterBank = 0;
            mCanFilter.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

            if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&mCanInstance, &mCanFilter) != HAL_OK)
            {
                // TODO_LOG
                while (1)
                {
                }
            }

            NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_RX0_IRQn,
                             NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(), CAN_RX_IRQ_PRIO, 0));
            __NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_RX0_IRQn);
            HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&mCanInstance, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);
            HAL_CAN_Start(&mCanInstance);
            while (1)
            {
            }
        }
```

STM32G4 configuration:

```
    hfdcan1.Init.ClockDivider = FDCAN_CLOCK_DIV1;
    hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
    hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
    hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
    hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
    hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
    hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 17;
    hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 1;
    hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 14;
    hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 5;
    hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 0;
    hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;
    hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
    if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    if (HAL_FDCAN_Start(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    while (1)
    {
        FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef header = {0};
        header.Identifier = 1;
        header.IdType = FDCAN_STANDARD_ID;
        header.TxFrameType = FDCAN_DATA_FRAME;
        header.ErrorStateIndicator = FDCAN_ESI_PASSIVE;
        header.BitRateSwitch = FDCAN_BRS_OFF;
        header.FDFormat = FDCAN_CLASSIC_CAN;
        header.DataLength = FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_3;
        header.TxEventFifoControl = FDCAN_NO_TX_EVENTS;
        header.MessageMarker = 0;

        uint8_t data[3] = {0xAA};

        if (HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &header, data) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }

        Delay_ms(5000);
    }
```

Comment: Without looking too much into this, have you verified each one of your devices (host/receiver)  are able to do their part with a 3d party CAN instrument? Even with something as simple as the Seeed CAN shield?